# using editActionsForRowAtIndexPath to delete a row "UITableView internal bug"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I need to create a action in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath to delete a row in a table. Following some research on the internet I came to this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


        let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Destructive, title: "Remover", handler: { (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in
            self.tableData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        })

        return [remove]
    }
```

but now I get this error

> UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with
>   old section count: 1 and new section count: 0

Comment: you don't need need to reload the table view

Comment: similarly, the error remains

Comment: is there any reason why you're using editAction method?

Comment: I m using editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: if I delete the first line a receive this:

Comment: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: @Lukas Yes, I am using the method since gotta change the title and add one more option for the User in addition to delete , are you br?

Answer (score 7):

When you delete a row from `UITableView`, you need to take care of two things.

First you should call `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` only after you remove the object from the data source already. Because it'll check for the count again and ensure that the resultant data source have one less value.

Now the second thing to remember is that the no. of section can't be 0 after you delete the last row. If you are returning 0 to `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, return 1 at least on empty row count. Another option is to actually delete the index too when you delete the last row.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use 'editActionsForRowAtIndexPath' method unless you implement your own custom accessory view but other wise you can use the standard swipe left gesture to delete rows and the delegate called is commitEditingStyle

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        tableData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
    else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        //edit cell
    }
}
//change the default 'Delete' text
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String? {
    return "Show this instead of delete"
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I can not use the boss method because when I not only have the delete function

Comment: can u explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes, when the User drag the cell to the left he will have two options, one is ready it is to edit an object, the second must delete this object and moreover must make a request deleting it from the database. The title of the delete option must also be different from the standard.

Comment: there is another delegate for that, to change the title. I'll add it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Do deleteRowsAtIndexPaths or reloadData, but not both.